# VBA On opening file check todays date is same as 1st day of the current Month and whether a cell range value is greater then 30 then run the rest

Tags: excel, vba, date

I would like the following to run if todays date equals the first the of the current month and if a cell value is greater than 30. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Please Help

```
copySheet.Unprotect
copySheet.Range("AB2").Copy
Sheets("Counter").Visible = True
pasteSheet.Unprotect
Sheets("Counter").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
pasteSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Counter").Visible = False
copySheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B5").Select
```

Bellow what complete.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastCounterVal As Range
Dim FirstDay As Date
Dim Today As Date
Dim pDate As Date


  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Counter")
  Set LastCounterVal = Worksheets("Counter").Range("D1")
  FirstDay = DateSerial(Year(pDate), Month(pDate), 1)
  Today = Date
  
  If FirstDay = Today And LastCounterVal > 30 Then


copySheet.Unprotect
copySheet.Range("AB2").Copy
Sheets("Counter").Visible = True
pasteSheet.Unprotect
Sheets("Counter").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
pasteSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Counter").Visible = False
copySheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    
    Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code not working? Are you getting errors? By the way, to check if today's date is the first of the month all you need is `Day(Date) = 1`.

Comment: You never assign a value to `pDate`

Comment: Hi, thank you. adding `Day(Date) = 1`, did the trick and much simpler and obvious.